# Different behavior when invoking function in ghci with variable vs literal number

Tags: haskell

I defined a simple function to find the absolute value of a number:

```
let abs n | n >= 0 = n | otherwise = -n
```

Calling the function with a variable

```
Prelude> let x = -10
Prelude| 
Prelude> abs x
10
```

Calling the function with a value

```
Prelude> abs -10
<interactive>:65:1:
  Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
  When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
    it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (a -> a), Ord a) => a -> a
```

I don't understand the failure of the second invocation. I am using GHCi, version 7.10.2.

Comment: please write a better, more precise title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abs -10` actually means `abs - 10`, the subtraction of `abs` and `10`.

You want `abs (-10)`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers it.